# Returning / Resolving object from action creator thunk - Is this okay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm quite new to react and redux, so I'm not quite sure if the following is considered as a good practice.

Im my case, I have a react-native project using redux as the state container. I have a plain `View` with an add-button. If the user clicks the button, an action creator is called, which will make a `GET` request to my webservice. The webservices returns a pre-filled object which I need to pass to the next navigator scene. Using `redux` - is it okay to rely on  the action after the promise has resolved? Or do I have to pull it from the state?

Button onPress Event:

```
addStory() {
  this.props.actions.createStory().then((action) => {
    Actions.editor({ title: action.story.title, action.story });
  });
}
```

Action Creator:

```
export function createStorySuccess(story) {
  return { type: CREATE_STORY_SUCCESS, story };
}

export function createStory() {
  return dispatch =>
    StoryApi.createStory().then((story) => {
      return dispatch(createStorySuccess(story));
    }).catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
}
```

Comment: What "it" would you pull from the state? Is it okay to rely on the action for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on Redux as far as you cover all the possible outcomes from promise. What I mean with this is that, instead of just throwing error, you also need to dispatch failure action, so your async action should look like this:

```
export function createStorySuccess(story) {
  return { type: CREATE_STORY_SUCCESS, story };
}

export function createStoryFailure(errorMessage) {
  return { type: CREATE_STORY_FAILURE, failed: true, errorMessage };
}

export function createStory() {
  return dispatch =>
    StoryApi.createStory().then((story) => {
      return dispatch(createStorySuccess(story));
    }).catch((error) => {
      return dispatch(createStoryFailure('Loading the story failed.'));
    });
}
```

You most probably need to add here fetching action too, when story is being fetched.

After that you can do something like this in your component:

```
let renderResult;
if(this.props.failed) {
   renderResult = <div> {this.props.errorMessage} </div>;
} else {
   renderResult = <div> {this.props.story} </div>;
}

return (renderResult)
```